# How to get users Facebook url likes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an app for facebook and I have several urls (e. www.mydomain.com/main/item/1) inside my app that are being liked. Is it possible for me to ask facebook api which of the links (from my domain) has user liked?

It seems I cant get URL likes from /{UID}/likes since it gives only fb page likes.

If there are extra permissions needed I may ask them but I cant seem to find the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extract details of likes, you need to make the call by appending access_token
more importantly, this access_token should be generated with fb permissions "user_likes,friends_likes"

simpler option would be to use social plugins, 
see;
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: with graph api call (having proper access token) im gettin only facebook page likes not the url outside facebook domain.

Comment: did you try to retrieve this way?  /{yourown_page_id_on_facebook/likes?access_token=

Comment: you can also do introspection to see what you can retrieve;  /{your_page_id_on_facebook)?metadata=1

Comment: let me try to explain better, i need to know if user has liked certain url (www.mydomain.com/item/1) not facebook page. Actually i need to retrieve all pages within my domain that user has liked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.  You can use FQL to see the data.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like